# Excel vlookup on 2 different columns with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
source data table:
date     quarter+1  quarter+2  quarter+3 quarter+4
07-Jan-2020 35.5000 39.4750 38.7000 38.0500
06-Jan-2020 36.4000 40.3250 39.2500 38.9000
03-Jan-2020 34.2500 41.7500 40.6750 40.2000
02-Jan-2020 32.9000 40.3500 39.3750 38.1250
31-Dec-2019 32.7500 40.5000 41.5000 40.6500
30-Dec-2019 39.0000 41.4250 42.0500 41.4500
27-Dec-2019 35.0000 42.8000 43.3250 42.7500
26-Dec-2019 35.0000 42.1000 43.0000 42.8000
24-Dec-2019 38.0000 42.7000 43.5000 42.7500
23-Dec-2019 39.7500 43.6500 44.6250 43.7000
.....         .....  .....   .....  .....

output table:
date      Apr-Jun20 Jul-Sep20 Oct-Dec20
07-Jan-2020 35.5000 39.4750 38.7000
06-Jan-2020 36.4000 40.3250 39.2500
03-Jan-2020 34.2500 41.7500 40.6750
02-Jan-2020 32.9000 40.3500 39.3750
31-Dec-2019 40.5000 41.5000 40.6500
30-Dec-2019 41.4250 42.0500 41.4500
27-Dec-2019 42.8000 43.3250 42.7500
26-Dec-2019 42.1000 43.0000 42.8000
24-Dec-2019 42.7000 43.5000 42.7500
23-Dec-2019 43.6500 44.6250 43.7000
```

Note: the data in each column (expect date) in the output table is different than the source data table from 23-Dec-2019 to 31-Dec-2019. For these dates the data is taken from the next column to the right in the source date table.

The logic:

- The source data is updated everyday so tomorrow a new row will be inserted for 08-Jan-2020 and so on.
- The column names in the output table are dynamic so name changes with every new quarter. For example: right now Column B is 'Apr-Jun20' then on 1st April 2020 the same cell will change to 'Jul-Sep20' and so on.
- I want to create a dynamic output table where IF Cell B1 = 'Apr-Jun20' I want to lookup the data from Column B in the source data only for dates 01-Jan-2020 to 30-Mar-2020 and Column C from 01-Oct-2019 to 31-Dec-2019. And if Cell C1 = 'Jul-Sep20' I want to lookup the data from Column C in the source data only for dates 01-Jan-2020 to 30-Mar-2020 and Column D from 01-Oct-2019 to 31-Dec-2019 and so on.
- Then when we hit the 1st April 2020 when Cell B1 in the output table changes to 'Jul-Sep20' I want to I want to lookup the data from Column B in the source data only for dates 01-Apr-2020 to 30-Jun-2020 and Column C from 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Mar-2019.

My attempt:

I have been able to work out the logic but despite playing around with multiple INDEX and MATCH I have not succeeded.

Comment: What is your question? Did you get stuck somewhere with your formula? Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have edited my question albeit with nothing much to add. I am stuck with the formula that I will need to use